# Minimize Size of Textblock

Tags: .net, wpf, windows, silverlight

Currently, if I have a `<TextBlock>` element with font size 200, the entire element takes up much more space than needed.

[image: Wasted Space]

The blue outline (from Blend) shows the space the element takes up, when easily half of that is needed. Is there anyway I can eliminate that space such that my elements are not spaced out so much? I've tried margin, padding etc but most methods don't seem to work.

[image: Ideal]

Ideally I would want the `<textblock>` to take up only the amount of space indicated by the red box

**Edit:**

[image: With Lower Cased Letters]

In response to stijn7, some space is indeed reserved for other letters (g,p,q etc). However there still is a lot of space at the top (1 is the highest character in Segoe UI). If clipping the textblock is not possible, is there anyway I can resize it such that there is no wasted space?

Comment: maybe it's like this because other characters need that space? interesting question nonetheless.

Comment: The top space is for special characters, like ^ and `, in various languages. If you look at Segoe in the Character Map, you can see these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the TextBlock has the height incorporates the [ascender and descender](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascender_%28typography%29) on order to render characters with a range of heights. The character you have chosen happens to span the font [x-height](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-height), but not beyond. In order to achieve the effect you are after you will need a slightly lower level text rendering API, I would suggest trying the [FormattedText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.formattedtext.aspx) class:

> Provides low-level control for drawing text in Windows Presentation
>   Foundation (WPF) applications.

This class has a [MaxTextHeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.formattedtext.maxtextheight.aspx) property. I have not tried this, but there is a chance it will give you the information you require.

Answer (score 1):

The TextBlock exposes two properties, LineHeight and LineStackingStrategy to manually set the height. Note that you have to set LineStackingStrategy to "BlockLineHeight" for the LineHeight to take effect.

```
<TextBlock LineHeight="180" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" Text="0" FontSize="200"/>
```